# read data set image with tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am a beginner in deep learning.
I'm working on an article that was posted on github. I downloaded the database which contains 6 types of images: glass, paper, cardboard, plastic, metal and trash.
My question is that I want to read the database as the author did but I can't read it, yet I gave the path correctly.
I show you the author's code to read for example the boxes and second my code that I made on google colab.

```
import copy
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

cardboard = []
for i in range(1,404):
    temp = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
        path = "trashnet/cardboard/cardboard"+str(i)+".jpg",
        grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb',target_size=(227,227))
    X = np.array(temp)
    cardboard.append(X)
cardboard = np.array(cardboard)
cardboard = np.take(cardboard,np.random.permutation(cardboard.shape[0]),axis=0)
print(cardboard.shape)
```

```
import copy
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
cardboard = []
for i in range(1,404):
    temp = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
        path="dataset-resized.zip/dataset-resized/cardboard"+str(i)+".jpg",
        grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb',target_size=(227,227))
    X = np.array(temp)
    cardboard.append(X)
cardboard = np.array(cardboard)
cardboard = np.take(cardboard,np.random.permutation(cardboard.shape[0]),axis=0)
print(cardboard.shape)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    111         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    112                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
--> 113     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    114         img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    115         if color_mode == 'grayscale':

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'dataset-resized.zip/dataset-resized/cardboard1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue using [Garbage Classification](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/asdasdasasdas/garbage-classification) dataset [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/c3c4f5e99878acb059ef6a331f0b8cf0/untitled184.ipynb). Please find the working code below and try passing the correct path to `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img`.

```
import copy
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

cardboard = []
for i in range(1,404):
    temp = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
        path = "/content/garbage classification/Garbage classification/cardboard/cardboard"+str(i)+".jpg",
        grayscale=False, color_mode='rgb',target_size=(227,227))
    X = np.array(temp)
    cardboard.append(X)
cardboard = np.array(cardboard)
cardboard = np.take(cardboard,np.random.permutation(cardboard.shape[0]),axis=0)
print(cardboard.shape)
```

Output:

```
(403, 227, 227, 3)
```